# How to use OpenNLP parser models in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, nlp, opennlp

I go through this link for java nlp https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opennlp/index.htm

I tried below code in android:

```
try {
   File file = copyAssets();
   // InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
   ParserModel model = new ParserModel(file);
   // Creating a parser
   Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
   // Parsing the sentence
   String sentence = "Tutorialspoint is the largest tutorial library.";
   Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(sentence, parser,1);
   for (Parse p : topParses) {
       p.show();
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

i download file `**en-parser-chunking.bin**` from internet and placed in assets of android project but code stop on third line i.e `ParserModel model = new ParserModel(file);` without giving any exception. Need to know how can this work in android? if its not working is there any other support for nlp in android without consuming any services?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code stalls/breaks at runtime is that you need to use an `InputStream` instead of a `File` to load the binary file resource. Most likely, the File instance is `null` when you "load" it the way as indicated in line 2. In theory, this constructor of `ParserModel`should detect this and an `IOException` should be thrown. Yet, sadly, the [JavaDoc of OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/parser/ParserModel.html#ParserModel-java.io.File-) is not precise about this kind of situation and you are not handling this exception properly in the `catch` block.

Moreover, the code snippet you presented should be improved, so that you know what actually went wrong.

Therefore, loading a `POSModel` from within an `Activity` should be done differently. Here is a variant that takes care for both aspects:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream in = null;

try {
    in = assetManager.open("en-parser-chunking.bin");
    POSModel posModel;
    if(in != null) {
        posModel = new POSModel(in);
        if(posModel!=null) {
            // From here, <posModel> is initialized and you can start playing with it...
            // Creating a parser
            Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
            // Parsing the sentence
            String sentence = "Tutorialspoint is the largest tutorial library.";
            Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(sentence, parser,1);
            for (Parse p : topParses) {
                p.show();
            }
        }
        else {
            // resource file not found - whatever you want to do in this case
            Log.w("NLP", "ParserModel could not initialized.");
        }
    }
    else {
        // resource file not found - whatever you want to do in this case
        Log.w("NLP", "OpenNLP binary model file could not found in assets.");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("NLP", "message: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    // proper exception handling here... 
} 
finally {
    if(in!=null) {
         in.close();
    }
}
```

This way, you're using an `InputStream` approach and at the same time you take care for proper exception and resource handling. Moreover, you can now use a Debugger in case something remains unclear with the resource path references of your model files. For reference, see the [official JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String)) of `AssetManager#open(String resourceName)`.

### Note well:

Loading OpenNLP's binary resources can consume quite a lot of memory. For this reason, it might be the case that your Android App's request to allocate the needed memory for this operation can or will not be granted by the actual runtime (i.e., smartphone) environment.
Therefore, carefully monitor the amount of requested/required RAM while `posModel = new POSModel(in);` is invoked.

Hope it helps.